# Continuous update of junit xml while test is running

Tags: pytest, jenkins-plugins

Here is how I am invoking pytest

```
pytest test.py -v -s -x --junitxml=junit.xml
```

What I see is that junit.xml gets produced at the end of the test. I am running the tests in Jenkins and I want to be able to use plugins like "Test In Progress" that will show the details of the in-progress/completed tests.

Is there a way to make pytest update xml file with the progress of the tests?

Comment: As far as I'm aware (though not 100% certain), even Java JUnit test runners will only generate the junit.xml at the very end. Are you sure that plugin uses plugin.xml to track progress, and not something else?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel good point. I was just guessing it uses that file.. Let me explore the plugin documentation (https://plugins.jenkins.io/testInProgress)